# If one thread writes data to its stack can other threads read from it?

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety

Also can threads from a completely other process read from it too?

Comment: It depends on... whether these are true operating system threads or something else? What language you are using? What threading API?

Answer (score 0):

First question: yes.
Second question: it depends. If different processes share memory (simply because the OS or the CPU do not support per-process address spaces), then yes. Otherwise, yes, only if the memory is explicitly shared.

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about normal OS threads, then yes, they can read each other's stacks. Because these stacks are in memory shared by all threads.

Completely different processes can't read each other stacks, cause their memory is not shared.